Why can class::A pass compile?
class A {
    public:
    A(){}
};
int main() {
    class::A* a = new class::A();
    return 0;
}


The code above passed compile, it seems that class:: makes no sense, and I wonder why class::A is legal in C++?
Is there some reason for that?

What command did you use for compiling?

@Rogue Compiles for me in gcc 14.2: https://godbolt.org/z/cnsWbP138

gcc, clang and MSVC accept it: https://godbolt.org/z/zhTjPGGKG.

@Dai @wohlstad I hadn't assumed it to be valid C++, I suppose it's akin to struct X foo. I asked anyhow in case of things like not enabling warnings and knowing what compiler they were on (in case it wasn't valid).

It's not parsed as *"class::" , it's "class ::A"

whitespace is confusing, you better remove all of it :D

@463035818_is_not_an_ai On the contrary...

The duplicate only answers half of the question, the class keyword part.

What the scope operator ( :: ) do in the class name

Each of these duplicates only describes half of the syntax. There's still the confusion that results from the combination.

The syntax classId is an elaborated type specifier. Only class types are considered when matching Id.
The syntax ::Id is a qualified-id. It looks for Id only in the global namespace.
The combination of the two means that we are looking for a class type in the global namespace, named A. This finds A, so your example compiles.
It would not find int A;, nor would it find namespace foo { class A{}; }, even within a function defined in namespace foo. Examples

First of all, we may note that ::A* a = new ::A(); compiles just as fine, the class (or struct etc) keyword is optional when declaring an object. It was always like that and I suspect compatibility with C was the reason.
:: is the scope resolution operator. It may be used without a left operand in which case it refers to the global scope. And since A was declared at that scope, ::A works. And we can conclude that A* a = new A(); without any namespace mentioned compiles just fine too.
Now what doesn't compile is if we do this:
namespace stuff {
  class A {
    public:
      A(){}
  };
}

int main() {
    ::A* a = new ::A();
    return 0;
}

Because A is not in the global namespace but in stuff. So stuff::A* a = new stuff::A(); would be correct.
We may now also note that stuff class::A is gibberish and invalid syntax. But class stuff::A would be allowed.

I suspect compatibility with C was the reason.  Of sorts.  For instance, in POSIX there is a struct stat and a int stat(char const*, struct stat*).  Since they have the same name, the stat type has to be elaborated with struct stat or class stat to disambiguate with the int stat() function.  C requires the struct elaboration, unless there is a typedef struct stat stat_t; helper (here with a different name to avoid colliding with the function).

@Eljay The proper solution would of course have been to give it a meaningful name instead. There is proper programming practices and then there is POSIX...

No argument from me.  I have a hard time telling apart C from Welsh.

The boring answer is: because the grammar of C++ allows it.
https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#nt:new-expression
new-expression:
  ::_opt new new-placement_opt new-type-id new-initializer_opt
  ...

new-type-id in turn contains type-specifier-seq, which contains type-specifier, which contains simple-type-specifier, which allows elaborated-type-specifier, which contains/allows class-key, which can be class. The elaborated-type-specifier also optionally contain a nested-name-specifier, which can be ::.

It is even required for disambiguation like in that Demo with (evil) A A;.
